# Why are only hard coded queries not returning an error when calling client.query in node-postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I'm extracting a SQL query from a webpage using puppeteer. When I pass the parsed query into the node-postgres client query method, I always get the error `syntax error at or near "."`.

When I console.log the query, and hard code into into client.query(), it runs fine. I can't for the life of me figure out why only the hard coded query is working.

I've tried using pg-escape, using dollar-quote string to pass the query, stripping spaces and newlines.

So in the scenarios are:

`puppeteer gets sql from webpage => parse and pass to node-postgres =>  get an error`

`puppeteer gets sql from webpage => parse and pass to console.log => manually copy and paste the query into a var => run the query with node-postgres => query success`

This is the query that I get when I console.log the extracted text from the webpage (this is after I clean it up):

```sql
SELECT
     cp.name AS category_page,
     cp.id AS category_page_id,
     cp.url AS category_page_url,
     ARRAY_AGG( DISTINCT g.name) AS projects,
     cp.created_by,
     date_trunc('day', (cp.created_date)::timestamp)::date AS created_date,
     cp.modified_by,
     date_trunc('day', (cp.modified_date)::timestamp)::date AS modified_date,
     cp.qa_by,
     date_trunc('day', (cp.qa_date)::timestamp)::date AS qa_date,
     cp.is_terminated,
     cp.annotation
 FROM ulta.category_page cp
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT c.*, a.name FROM ulta.category_page_to_ref_resource_group c
    LEFT JOIN ref.resource_group a ON a.id = c.ref_resource_group_id) AS g
 ON g.category_page_id = cp.id
 WHERE (g.ref_resource_group_id='109')
   AND (cp.id='4')
 GROUP BY cp.id
 ORDER BY cp.name
 limit 5000
```

I'm running:

```javascript
console.log(query)
try {
     const results = await postgres.query(query);
     console.log(results);
} catch(err) {
     console.error(err);
}
```

When I throw this in a debugger and break at the query, the only difference that I find is that are `\n` when they are not stripped. Otherwise it looks exactly the same.

Any help is greatly appreciated! I'm assuming it has something to do with the way console.log prints a string and the way node-postgres handles strings.

***EDIT***

Adding the console.log results of JSON.stringify per the comment:

```
" SELECT\n     cp.name AS category_page,\n     cp.id AS category_page_id,\n     cp.url AS category_page_url, \n     ARRAY_AGG( DISTINCT g.name) AS projects,\n     cp.created_by, \n     date_trunc('day', (cp.created_date)::timestamp)::date AS created_date,\n     cp.modified_by, \n     date_trunc('day', (cp.modified_date)::timestamp)::date AS modified_date,\n     cp.qa_by, \n     date_trunc('day', (cp.qa_date)::timestamp)::date AS qa_date, \n     cp.is_terminated,\n     cp.annotation\n FROM ulta.category_page cp\n LEFT JOIN (SELECT c.*, a.name FROM ulta.category_page_to_ref_resource_group c\n    LEFT JOIN ref.resource_group a ON a.id = c.ref_resource_group_id) AS g\n ON g.category_page_id = cp.id\n WHERE (g.ref_resource_group_id='109')\n AND (cp.id='4')\n GROUP BY cp.id\n ORDER BY cp.name\n limit 5000\n"
```

***EDIT 2***
After parsing the sql query with JSON.stringify I was able to find the culprits. I added:

```
        const parsedQuery = JSON.stringify(query)
        .replace(/\\n/g, '')
        .replace(/"/g, '')
        .replace(/\s{4,5}/g, ' ')
        .trim()
```

Which solved the issue. I'm still unsure why this needed.

Comment: Could you include the raw result of `console.log(JSON.stringify(query))`, right before the `postgres.query` line?

Comment: @sachav I've updated my post with the console.log of the JSON.stringify

Comment: You can safely sterilize and prepare your SQL with [pg-minify](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-minify) ;)